# What is "pvt" in the Visual Studio Debugger?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm debugging a Qualcomm BREW program I wrote that has weird pointer/memory issues.

The value for "pfile" is listed as this in the "Autos" subwindow:

```
0x046641f8 {pvt=0x0062f798}
```

The first one is the pointer, I got that. But what is this "pvt" and what does "pvt" stand for?

Comment: Can you tag this with the relevant language please, as well as a minimal reproducible example of code (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: C++. The language is C++.

Comment: And a minimal reproducible example? The question is too vague for anyone to help you.

Comment: There's no need to be rude. Neither I, nor anyone else, can see your screen and it's hard to guess at anything from such little information. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Ask about how a tool works, and you get requested for your work...

It's a pointer to a "Virtual Method Table". An array containing function pointers. Basically, it's an artifact of Qualcomm BREW's "Component Object Model".

Qualcomm BREW is WEIRD.